# Dynamic Matrix Generator Class

Tags: java, android, algorithm, dynamic, matrix

I need a dynamic matrix generator class which will return me an `int[4][4]` matrix, **values should be between 1 to 16** and **there would be no repetitive values.**

Matrix solutions will be somthing like this:

[image]  or [image]

If you carefully observe the matrix image then you will find **every matrix have a particular logic/pattern** in the position of the values of the matrix. It is not important that what is the pattern, but it is **important** to maintain a pattern (*it means there should be a pattern of any type*). currently I am using static code like:

```
// for the second image    
int temp4[][] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 12, 13, 14, 5 },
                        { 11, 16, 15, 6 }, { 10, 9, 8, 7 } };
```

Currently I have 3/4 static pattern, but implementing this statically is a bad approach, so it should be dynamic because I need random patterns runtime.

So my question is: *Is it possible to make a solution like this ??  What would be the code ??* If you know a link related to this then please post it or post the raw code.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

What is the **pattern** means for this question ??

If you carefully follow the 1st matrix you will find the number are like 1st row: 1,2,3,4 then 2nd row: 5,6,7,8 and so on..

for 2nd matrix its 1st row is 1,2,3,4 then it comes downwards as 5,6,7 then returns back as 8,9,10 ans so on.

Another pattern may be like this 1st column: 1,2,3,4 then 2nd column: 5,6,7,8 so the matrix will look like:

1  5  9  13

2  6  10  14

3  7  11  15

4  8  12  16 .. and so on

Thus I need a matrix generator which will return `int[4][4]` with non repetitive value from 1 to 16, and values should be in a order. another pattern may be like:

[image] and [image]

and the patterns of the above 2 are like this:

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you post the pattern. By the two examples there, the community can't guess the whole pattern, just to make some assumptions that maybe won't suit for your needs.

Comment: If you want to write a program for this, you have to define what a 'pattern' is. To get any random matrix without repeating numbers, start with a valid one and then swap some digits randomly.

Comment: let me think, before editing my post because probably its became harder for me to describe the **pattern**

Comment: so, the number 1 will be in a corner always?

Comment: **NO** in my example position of one is 0,0... but you may start from 3,3 then a possible pattern of the matrix will be 16,15,14,13 -> 12,11,10,9 -> 8,7,6,5 -> 4,3,2,1

Comment: @SoumyadipDas that's what I've asked, will the number 1 always be in **a** (not the) corner: (0,0), (0,3), (3,0) or (3,3)?

Comment: please check the new pattern I just added

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it may be, or may not be... it depends how you want to arrange the entire matrix

Comment: @SoumyadipDas its not so hard to do (I just don't have the time). Start your matrix with -1 value (this will be a blank) for all entries, then set the starting position (by random values) and start  updating it changing the -1 value for 1, 2, 3... by following a path. The path will be defined by the next position from the actual. To define **next**, you can look at the actual position and add +1 or -1 to the X or Y position, and the next position should be blank (-1 value), if there are no blanks, then go back and keep doing the work. Definitely, this would be a backtracking algorithm

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes sir, you logic is helpful, I will try to implement the logic. In the mean time if you find an algorithm, then please post it here. & just now I updated an image to describe the pattern, probably it will solve evereyones confusion that what's the pattern is in this problem... thank you

Comment: @SoumyadipDas did you make the program? I'm just curious about this kind of questions that I don't have enough time to answer.

Comment: I havn't tried your logic yet, though I think your logic is ok to solve my prob. But one thing in my mind that this type of complex logic may have impact of app's performance. So its necessary to check this issue before implementing in actual code. So as I am in hurry & completion the app is first priority, so I decided to implement the default array initialization technique for now. Later I will work on this. Actually I faced difficulty to express this question properly, I think. So in future probably I will modify this question for better ans. & if I get succeeded, I will post my code also.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update I would create a Strategy for each pattern.  In each pattern you can choice a starting point, a direction, and ascending or descending (if that is allowed)

Once you have a set of patterns, you can choice one at random and randomise it, or generate every possible pattern and select one at random.

---

You can generate non repeating values in a random order using Collections.shuffle()

You can then test your matrix to see if it has enough patterns or is acceptable.  If not, repeat until you do.

Comment: I can do this, but the problem is how to check the pattern? probably its the toughest part of this code.

Comment: The toughest part is defining what is a pattern.